# Closed form of $\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{1-x^{2-x^{3-...}}}dx\end{align}$.

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, recursion, power-towers

I want to find the closed form of $\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{1-x^{2-x^{3-...}}}dx\end{align}$.

*Quick disclaimer: I have no reason to believe one actually exists*

Using Desmos, the closest I have gotten is $1.2421832267$.

I have noticed that when it is repeated an odd amount of times, for example $x^{1-x^{2-x^3}}$ the integral does not converge and I would have to change it to $x^{1-x^{|2-x^3|}}$. Is there any way to avoid having to do this (perhaps with a slightly altered equation)? My question is still for the closed form.

I first tried to find the closed form by putting it in Desmos and then plugging the decimal it gave me into WolframAlpha in hopes of getting a closed form but it didn't give me anything, even after I wrote a Python script so I could copy and paste 200 repetitions into Desmos in an attempt to get a more accurate decimal.

Here is my other approach:

The closed form of $\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{1-x^{2-x^{3-...}}}dx\end{align}$ is equal to $\begin{align}\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{0}^{a}x^{1-x^{2-x^{3-...}}}dx\end{align}$.

This is where I am stuck. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The expression is not clear, do you mean $x^{(1-x)^{(2-x)^\cdots}}$ ?

Comment: No, I mean $x^{1-(x^{2-(x^{...})})}$

Comment: Your integrand is this Wolfram Alpha [command](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Fold%5Bx%5E%28%232-%231%29%26%2C+0%2C+Reverse%5BRange%5B1%2C5%5D%5D%5D) if it helps

Comment: Is this the Somophore's nightmare ? (kidding). Interesting problem. If you want 50 exact decimal places, it is $$1.2421832266975400643278225490476835939896793761402$$ which is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

Comment: Thanks! What did you do to get 50 decimals? I wanted to try the inverse symbolic calculator but I could only find as many characters as I had given before.

Comment: Compared to $1.24218322669754$ :

The ISC (from CECM) gives this approximate : $\frac{1}{10}\left((-\psi(1/10)-\psi(2/5)+\psi(3/5)-\psi(9/10)\right)\simeq 1.24218320191565$ where $\psi$ is the digamma function. The first 8 digits are correct.

My own ISC gives $\ln\left(\frac{\sin(1)}{\sin(C)}\right)-\sin\left(5-\ln(2)\right)\simeq 1.242183226717452$ where $C$ is the Catalan constant. The first 10 digits are correct. Of course all this isn't serious.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici. Hi! Claude. Always ready !  Even for a lost cause. Cheers.

Comment: @JJacquelin. Hi Jean ! Good to see you here. Cheers :-)

Comment: Still kidding. Let $a$ be the number $$a^{3528}-\left\lfloor a^{3528}\right\rfloor=0.000182987$$

Comment: It may be best to find a closed form for the integrand

Comment: This is some kind of recursive definition, but I fail to see the precise definition here. How is that sequence of functions really defined? How do we know it is convergent?

Comment: @freakish I appreciate the help. I do not have much experience with convergence and definitely not any with a function like this one. What test could I conduct to determine if it is convergent? I thought it appeared to converge at around 1.2421832267.

Comment: @DylanLevine well, we could start with a definition. Triple dots symbol is not good enough, it is not a proper definiton. So for example $1+2+3+\cdots$ is actually defined as $x_1=1$, and $x_n=x_{n-1}+n$, and then the triple dots is simply taking a limit of $x_n$ (if it exists). That's what I call a precise definition. It is more precise. But I can't seem to convert your triple dot definition into something like here, not in a simple, useful way.

Answer (score 2):

I was hoping to provide something for the $\huge \pi$ day.

For an error of $1.33\times 10^{-51}$, the number

$${\large\Xi}=1.2421832266975400643278225490476835939896793761402$$ (obtained using $88$ levels) is such that it could write
$$8058940\,{\large\Xi}=-5866165 \binom{\pi }{\pi !}+4785910 \binom{\pi !}{\pi }-14882994 \binom{\pi !}{\log (\pi )}+$$ $$12531710 \binom{\log (\pi )}{\pi !}-14673958
   \binom{\pi }{\log (\pi )}-761197 \binom{\log (\pi )}{\pi }$$ which $\cdots\cdots$ does not mean anything.